# Why when bar is called it writes to same stack location as "foo" for local variable?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I don't understand why when bar is called it writes to same stack location as "foo" for local variable?

Unsure why this does output

$ gcc -O 3 test.c -o mytest
local foo is 10
local foo is 12

. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int initialize, int val)
{
    int local;

    if (initialize) {
        local = val;
    } else {
        printf("local foo is %d\n", local);
    }

}

int bar(int initialize, int val)
{
    int local;

    if (initialize) {
        local = val;
    } else {
        printf("local bar is %d\n", local);
    }

}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 10); //set to 10
    foo(0, 0); //print it
    bar(1, 12); //set to 12
    foo(0, 0); //print foo again

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Both of them aren't in scope at the same time and using the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior) and [Why does the C standard leave use of indeterminate variables undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248118/why-does-the-c-standard-leave-use-of-indeterminate-variables-undefined) are worth reading.

Comment: "Location"?  You are printing an uninitialized value as a decimal (number).  If you want the address it's `... "%p", (void *) &local)`.  Your implementation probably uses a call stack and it's pretty natural that an (almost) identical function would end up storing variables at the same location.

Comment: Also, you should refactor your two function into one by passing the the string that differ.

Comment: You say `foo()` and `bar()` return an `int` but you don't have any return statement in either.

Comment: @AllanWind Sorry, I meant print

Comment: > Why wouldn't it? Both of them aren't in scope at the same time and using the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

@RetiredNinja Are you saying that this is just how gcc and clang do it? Since it is "undefined behavior" a compiler could do whatever it wants to?